# Symfony3 - Switch DB Connection Based on Sub Domain

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I need to be able to match a connection / entity manager with a sub domain:

- **one.domain.com** => Should use connection and entity manager `one`
- **two.domain.com** => Should use connection and entity manager `two`

But I'm not sure how to best achieve this, what would be the correct way of approaching it in Symfony3.4?

#### My Doctrine Configuration

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: one
        connections:
            one:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                etc...
            two:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                etc...

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        default_entity_manager: one
        entity_managers:
            one:
                connection: one
                mappings:
                    UserBundle: ~
                    AnotherBundle: ~
                    YetAnotherBundle: ~
            two:
                connection: two
                mappings:
                    UserBundle: ~
                    AnotherBundle: ~
```

Comment: I would use an environment to be loaded, based on the domain you want the configuration of. Then you can separate the `default_entity_manager` accordingly by loading it within your `app/config_[environment].yml`, from the `web/app.php` as `new AppKernel('two_domain_com')` This also reduces the overhead of each domain by only needing to configure one entity manager to be loaded by the compiler. You would just need to switch the usage of `app.php` in your server configuration for that domain. ie. making `web/app_one` and `web/app_two` and using them instead of the default `web/app`.

Comment: For more details see the Symfony Documentation on [How to Master and Create new Environments](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration/environments.html)

Comment: @fyrye Thanks for replying! Unfortunately, splitting the kernel isn't an option at the moment, but it looks like creating a doctrine connection wrapper might do the trick.